# How to Move Agents as a Group Through AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

My project team for a class is modeling a theme park area's operations in AnyLogic. We have agents from the Pedestrian library entering the area and queuing for one of two roller coasters. Each coaster has its own defined operation steps.
When I run the simulation, agents are going through these steps of the coaster one at a time, instead of as a group (there should be 21 people simultaneously moving through the steps like boarding, riding, and exiting). Is it possible to group agents together to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can best be modelled by an agent using **Pickup** object. This way agents wait somewhere to be picked up (like a roller-coaster picks up passengers) and then, once the ride is over they will be released. For details please consult help [here](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/pickup.html#pickup).